# How do I pass an array parameter to powershell -file?

Tags: powershell, command-line

I have the following powershell script:

```
param(
    [Int32[]] $SomeInts = $null, 
    [String]$User = "SomeUser", 
    [String]$Password = "SomePassword"
)

New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    Integers = $SomeInts;
    Login = $User;
    Password = $Password;
} | Format-List
```

If I execute `.\ParameterTest.ps1 (1..10)` I get the following:

```
Password : SomePassword
Login    : SomeUser
Integers : {1, 2, 3, 4...}
```

However, I don't get the expected results if I run it in a separate powershell instance like this `powershell -file .\ParameterTest.ps1 (1..10)`. In that case I get the following:

```
Password : 3
Login    : 2
Integers : {1}
```

My question is how can I pass the array, or other complex data type from a command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to use `powershell.exe -EncodedCommand` and to base64 encode the parameters. The description for this is on the [PowerShell.exe Console Help](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315276.aspx) technet page. I have compressed their version of the ceremony to do this into a one-liner:

```
powershell.exe -EncodedCommand "$([Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes('.\ParameterTest.ps1 (1..10)')))"
```

Answer (score 6):

The individual elements of the array (`1..10`) are being passed as parameters to the script.

An alternative would be to do:

```
powershell -command {.\test.ps1 (1..10)}
```

For a version that works both from powershell console and cmd:

```
powershell -command "&.\test.ps1 (1..10)"
```

Comment: That's simpler then -EncodeCommand, and will work from cmd.exe as well.